# pandas TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'storage_options'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, visual-studio-code

This is the code example I'm trying to run.

```
df = pd.read_csv(
         "s3://noaa-ghcn-pds/csv/by_station/USC00118740.csv",
         storage_options={"anon": True},  # passed to `s3fs.S3FileSystem`
         dtype={'Q_FLAG': 'object', 'M_FLAG': 'object'},
         parse_dates=['DATE']
     ).set_index('DATE')
```

It works for everyone else in my class, but I keep getting this error in Visual Code Studio.

```
TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'storage_options'
```

How do I go about fixing it?

Comment: The option is new in Pandas 1.2 so check what version of Pandas you have installed. It's probably something old

Comment: I have Pandas 1.5 I believe

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code just needed to be restarted. It worked after that. Thanks for the help anyways!